# Laravel and Vue: where to put js/app.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.5

I created a simple app using some Vue components and a Bootstrap component (carousel).

I compile my assets using Laravel Mix. When I put the compiled app.js between the head tags, my Vue components do not work (`Cannot find element: #app`). When I put the app.js just before the `</body>` tag, my carousel (the [indicators](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators)) does not work ... I also tried with the `defer` attribute, but no success. Do I have to split my JavaScript-files to make both work?

Edit:

When I put my asset just before the `</body>` tag, the indicators of the carousel looks like this: `<="" li="">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, before the ending `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

And if you have other bootstrap specific js codes, you have to write them after the above-mentioned script tag because `app.js` is also responsible for loading bootstrap required js files in the `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` file.

Comment: I am not writing other js codes, just the html needed to make the carousel work. But apparently bootstrap.js must run before the html .. because my carousel works when I put the compiled app.js in the header...

Comment: But what if the compiled app.js contains jquery library? Now I cannot write any jquery at the top of the page because using Vue requires me to put app.js at the bottom before ending /body tag.. I really dont see any way of compiling Vue and Jquery in the same app.js file as these two require to be placed at different position in the html

Comment: how can i acces variable defined on app.js in another js file?

Answer (score 2):

The message `Cannot find element: #app` does not mean, that vue do not work. It means, that Vue.js is mounted correctly but it can not find any div with the id of `app`:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

To include an js file I would recommend the `asset()` helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: My Vue scripts work when I put the asset file before the ending </body> tag. It's just that I want my carousel and Vue components to work at the same time.

Comment: Habe you put it in the head and added the div like I said?

Comment: yes! I've put it in the head and I have the div like you said, but it does not render because the head is loaded before the body I guess..

Comment: Do you find solution about this issue?