# Laravel-Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

i'am trying to attach a vue component with a tag

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

this is app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import MyComponent from './components/MyComponent.vue';

Vue.component('myComponent', MyComponent);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

And this is the body of my welcome.blade

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <myComponent></myComponent>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

and i get this error

Unknown custom element: mycomponent - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: check public/js/app.js file is there if not then run npm run watch comand

Answer (score 0):

try this  as vuejs use case sensitive

```js
Vue.component('my-component', require('./components/MyComponent.vue').default);
```

and html

```php
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <my-component></my-component>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

ref link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

Comment: @user7385152 import same as i m doing and compile your js

Answer (score 0):

In general, before the ending `</body>` tag.
[Check this link for referance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792174/8863063)

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <my-component></my-component>
  </div>

   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```